Azure Devops Server 2020 update 1.2 - classic build (CI) pipeline - triggers - Azure Git path filters
Recently I got stuck about defining Include and Exclude paths when trying to set CI pipeline to be run only for certain paths.
In my Azure Git repo, I have

1 larger solution having multiple projects that work together (they reference their neighbour projects)
-- eg. MyProj.Model, myProj.ServiceLayer, ... (all in root of repo)
some individual solutions, that don't take part in the large solution as they can be run solely
-- they are in subfolder "otherProjects", like "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1/.." and so on.

Paths example

otherProjects


MyIndividualSln1/...




MyIndividualSln2/...


MyProj.DataAccessLayer
MyProj.Model
MyProj.ServiceLayer (and so on...)
MyProj.sln

"otherProjects" individual solutions CI pipelines
Setting Trigger using classic pipeline (clickable graphic dialogs) to:

branch "dev"
path filters - Include - "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1/**" (asterisks at the end)

does NOT trigger on changes under MyIndividualSln1 path.
After some investigation I found out, that when I specify the path to include only:
Include - "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln"
the trigger works as intended (any change in that path or any deeper).
But such setting does not fit the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#example
I also tried to download exported pipeline as YML. It is stating the same values that I wrote to the classic pipeline (no * added to path implicitly).
Can, please, anyone explain, why is that happening?

I can reproduce the same issue on my Azure DevOps Server 2020 update 1.2 that the classic build pipeline is not triggered when using "**" at the end of path filter pattens (e.g., the patten "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1/**").
However, when I attempted the same patten on Azure DevOps Services (cloud) and Azure DevOps Server 2022, it can work as expected.
On Azure DevOps Server 2020, I also attempted the following two pattens:

otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1/*
otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1

Both can work as expected that any files get changed under the 'MyIndividualSln1' folder or its sub-folders, the pipeline can be triggered.
It seems that using "**" at the end of wildcards patterns is not accepted for the path filters on Azure DevOps Server 2020.
For your case, if you want to keep Azure DevOps Server 2020, you can use any of above two pattens which can work as expected.
You also can try to update your server to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server 2022 so that the patten "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1/**" also can work.

Thank you for your further elaboration.
In my scenarios I can live with it as described since the mechanism got revealed. The only sad thing about it is, that the official sites do not describe the process/settings right... :)

@VladimírHála, From the docs you mentioned above, we can all the examples for path filters are using the pattens like as "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1/*" and "otherProjects/MyIndividualSln1", no one is end with "**" (double asterisks). And the docs also has stated that including "*" (single asterisk) as the final character doesn't do anything differently from specifying the directory name by itself.

@VladimírHála, The docs also has mentioned that the accepted pattens might be different in different versions of Azure DevOps.
